# Unable to access sub directories / folders with Magento installed at root?

Tags: .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I installed Magento at the root of my domain and I'm trying to install a forum to the sub folder at mydomain.com/forum/ but it seems the .htaccess of Magento (located at mydomain.com/.htaccess of course) is preventing any requests to the sub-directory /forum/.

Whenever I access /forum/ or /anything it just gives 404 error instead of serving the actual files located there.

Any idea I can fix this without breaking the URL rewriting for Magento? It's very annoying....

Thank you!

Comment: What's the htaccess look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.

Seems it's a permission issue because I had suPHP installed. While I did chmod everything under /forums/ to be 644 for files and 755 for folders, I didn't do so for /forums/ itself.

```
chown -R youruser /home/youruser/public_html/forums
chgrp -R youruser /home/youruser/public_html/forums
find /home/youruser/public_html/forums -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find /home/youruser/public_html/forums -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

suPHP: http://www.kavoir.com/2012/10/500-internet-server-error-for-incorrect-permissions-after-installing-suphp-and-uploading-php-script.html

After chmod /forums/ itself to be 755, mydomain.com/forums/ is correctly accessible without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

I don't seem to have this problem with my magento install. Try creating a test folder in docroot and put an index.php file in there. Then navigate to mydomain.com/test/ and you should see the contents of your index.php. Also check that your magento .htaccess file has these lines:

```
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

Perhaps your forum has its own .htaccess that is causing 404s? Your forum may need to specify

```
    RewriteBase /forum/
```

Comment: Thank you, Jamie. Seems it's a permission issue.